# Power BI measure with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

It's a silly power BI question, but I can't figure it out using measures.
This is a condition that I'd like to convert into a measure.

Condition:

i.) When there is **no** flight time for direction 'APAC' AND the first character in the code is 'V', will return '0', otherwise '1'.But other than code start with 'V', with or without date, will return **blank**.

ii.) When there is **no** flight time for direction 'AMER', will return **'0'**

iii.) Direction 'EMEA' , with or without time flight, will return **blank**

Expected result:

[image]

Attached with pbix: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PEkk4PX37H4w8_1c6Dcl_TpEUa8IpEmW/view?usp=sharing

Appreciate any helps provided !

Comment: Please add your data in tabular text format instead of as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one as a **calculated column**:

```
Result = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    FlightTable[Direction] = "APAC", 
        IF( 
            LEFT(FlightTable[Code], 1) = "V", 
            IF (FlightTable[Flight Time] = BLANK(), 0,  1),
            BLANK()
        ),
    FlightTable[Direction] = "APAC", 
        IF(LEFT(FlightTable[Code], 1) = "V", 0, BLANK()),
    FlightTable[Direction] = "AMER", 
        IF( FlightTable[Flight Time] = BLANK(), 0, 1),
    FlightTable[Direction] = "EMEA", BLANK(),
    BLANK()
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution should be as follows

measue= Switch ( True(),

if(condition1,"Result1"  ,

```
if(condition1,"Result1"  ,
```

etc...                     )

this should give you what you need, because Switch in DAX acts as if & else if

Answer (score 0):

Here is a measure you can use, based on your stated logic.

Use `SWITCH` with `TRUE` as the first argument. The first `SWITCH` predicate that returns `TRUE` will be used as the result for each row.

```
Result = 
VAR _dir = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Direction] )
VAR _code = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Code] )
VAR _time = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Flight Time] )
VAR _out = 
    SWITCH ( 
        TRUE , 
        _time = BLANK () && _dir = "AMER" , 0 , // If direction is AMER with no flight time, return 0
        _dir = "EMEA" , BLANK () , // If direction is EMEA, return blank with or without flight time
        _dir = "APAC" && LEFT(_code, 1) <> "V" , BLANK () , // If direction is APAC but code does not start with V, return blank
        _time = BLANK () && _dir = "APAC" && LEFT(_code,1) = "V" , 0 , // When there is no flight time for APAC, and code starts with V, return 0
        1 // Else 1
    )
RETURN
    _out
```

[image]